# Get all text nodes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

In jquery we can select an element using:

```
$(#elem).get();
```

is their a way to select all text nodes of an element using jquery ?

Comment: [Do you mean all `Node.TEXT_NODE` elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/298750/417685)

Comment: See [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents)

Comment: This question is already answered I guess !!!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery) is the same question

try this:

```
$(elem)
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
  });
```

Comment: @Asad I will accept this answer in 10 min.

Comment: This code, including the comment, is verbatim from an answer in the linked question. Please attribute where attribute is due. =)

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
$('#elem *').contents().filter(function() { 
    return (this.nodeType == 3); 
});
```

Comment: It should be the accepted answer

Comment: Exactly. This goes into all the levels inside #elem. This should have been accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .text() to get the text of an element, but I don't know if this will do exactly what you want. It's not clear from your question, but are you looking for something which would match only text nodes in the same way you can in XSLT? For example, a snippet like this:

```
<p>This is <strong>a typical</strong> line of <em>text</em>
```

Would result in 4 matched text nodes in XSLT. Is this what you meant?