# wrap numbers in span and .not()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is similar to other questions, but it's about something specific.

The first example doesn't do anything (breaks)

The second example works except that it hacks up html tags (specifically `a` tags) as well, so `href="something with numbers"` get hashed and then the whole thing falls apart

Then I get anchors that have their `href` attributes hashed up with `span` tags. Obviously that isn't what I want.  What am I doing wrong? There must be some way to put all numbers and ", - : ()" inside a `span` without hashing up the html tags themselves.

```
$('#main-content p').contents().not("a").html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace( /([0-9(),-:]+)/g , '<span class="number">$1</span>');
});


$('#main-content p').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace( /([0-9(),-:]+)/g , '<span class="number">$1</span>');
});
```

Comment: You were on the right path with .contents(), you then need to filter the contents to only text nodes (type = 3), and then loop over each one doing the replace on it's node value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing all number.  You need to only select the text nodes within the element.  This code is not tested, but should work.

EDIT:  You have to also call .contents().  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233808/get-all-text-nodes-using-jquery)

EDIT 2:  I got it working in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X98Eh/).  Let me know what you think.  Did you mean to replace special characters as well as numbers?....because that is what is currently happening per your original regEx.

```
$('p').contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3; }).each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text().replace( /([0-9(),-:]+)/g , 
    '<span class="number">$1</span>'));
 });
```

Comment: `$('#main-content p').filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3; })` will be empty, because `p` elements have `nodeType == 1`

Comment: ok, indeed this.nodeType === 3 did not work
nodeType == 1 leaves me with the same problem, hashed up anchor tags

Comment: thank you, but I tried both again, still no good, with .contents() this time

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can test it?

Comment: sorry, I've never really used fiddle before,
I tried to do something here
http://jsfiddle.net/2t54V/

Sorry I'm not a better help

Comment: ok, I got it working in jsfiddle.  I mean I got jsfiddle working.  the question is still not solved.  thanks for everyone for helping

Comment: Ok.  It works now without destroying your a tag.  I changed the href because it was throwing an error for google maps.